# C - Force a macro argument to be a string literal

Tags: c, strings, macros, c-preprocessor

The requirement is to define a macro which takes a single argument that is a string literal.

My first try at it was to surround it with empty string literals (I got this from Modern C):

```c
#define SV(str)    (sizeof("" str "") - 1)
```

Now if I do:

```c
int main(void)
{
    static const char *const s = "hello";
    char word[] = "hello";
    double a = 0.0f;
    double *d = &a;

    printf("%zu\n", SV(NULL));
    printf("%zu\n", SV(word));
    printf("%zu\n", SV(d));
    printf("%zu\n", SV(s));

    return 0;
}
```

It fails to compile, which was the expected behavior:

```
macro_str.c: In function ‘main’:
macro_str.c:4:33: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
    4 | #define SV(str)         (sizeof("" str "") - 1)
      |                                 ^~
macro_str.c:19:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘SV’
   19 |     printf("%zu\n", SV(NULL));
      |                     ^~
macro_str.c:4:40: error: expected ‘)’ before string constant
    4 | #define SV(str)         (sizeof("" str "") - 1)
      |                                ~       ^~
macro_str.c:19:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘SV’
   19 |     printf("%zu\n", SV(NULL));
      |                     ^~
macro_str.c:20:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘word’
   20 |     printf("%zu\n", SV(word));
      |                        ^~~~
macro_str.c:4:36: note: in definition of macro ‘SV’
    4 | #define SV(str)         (sizeof("" str "") - 1)
      |                                    ^~~
macro_str.c:4:32: note: to match this ‘(’
    4 | #define SV(str)         (sizeof("" str "") - 1)
      |                                ^
macro_str.c:20:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘SV’
   20 |     printf("%zu\n", SV(word));
      |                     ^~
macro_str.c:21:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘d’
   21 |     printf("%zu\n", SV(d));
      |                        ^
macro_str.c:4:36: note: in definition of macro ‘SV’
    4 | #define SV(str)         (sizeof("" str "") - 1)
      |                                    ^~~
macro_str.c:4:32: note: to match this ‘(’
    4 | #define SV(str)         (sizeof("" str "") - 1)
      |                                ^
macro_str.c:21:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘SV’
   21 |     printf("%zu\n", SV(d));
      |                     ^~
macro_str.c:22:24: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘s’
   22 |     printf("%zu\n", SV(s));
      |                        ^
macro_str.c:4:36: note: in definition of macro ‘SV’
    4 | #define SV(str)         (sizeof("" str "") - 1)
      |                                    ^~~
macro_str.c:4:32: note: to match this ‘(’
    4 | #define SV(str)         (sizeof("" str "") - 1)
      |                                ^
macro_str.c:22:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘SV’
   22 |     printf("%zu\n", SV(s));
      |                     ^~
make: *** [<builtin>: macro_str] Error 1
```

Then I proceeded to ask a question on StackOverflow and found instances where this would fail:

```c
SV()
SV(/*comment*/)
SV(-)
SV("abc" - "def")
```

So I added some more expressions , suggested by @n. m. could be an AI, to it:

```
#define SV(str)    ("" str "", (str)[0], sizeof(str) - 1)
```

Now it fails for these 4 edge-cases as well. Yet there are still things like:

```
// I believe the second one is defined-behavior. 
SV("abcd" - sizeof "e");  
SV("abcd" + sizeof "e");
```

for which it would compile cleanly. Whilst I am satisfied with the final macro and it serves my use-case, I believe there might still be some improvements it could use.

How can it be made more robust?

Note: I am looking for a solution that would work with at least C99.

Comment: This was a simple use-case. A better use case is for a `debug_print(s, x)` wrapper around `fprintf(stderr, s, x)` where `s` is required to be a string literal for security purposes.

Comment: The use-case seems similar to [Stringizing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html). You'll still end up with situations where you can't stringify empty arguments or comments.